# python & pandas: get average rank

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame

```
ID    2014-01-01    2015-01-01     2016-01-01
1     NaN           0.1            0.2                           
2     0.1           0.3            0.5
3     0.2           NaN            0.7
4     0.8           0.4            0.1
```

For each date(col), I want to get the rank of each id. For example, in col '2014-01-01', id = 4 has greatest value, so we assign rank 1 to id = 4. id = 3 has second greatest value, so we give it rank 2. If the data is NaN, just ignore it.

```
ID    2014-01-01    2015-01-01     2016-01-01
1     NaN           3              3                           
2     3             2              2
3     2             NaN            1
4     1             1              4
```

Next step is to get the average rank of each id. Fore example, AvgRank of id1 = (4+3)/2 = 3.5 and AvgRank of id2 = (3+2+2)/3 = 2.33

```
ID    AvgRank
1     3                         
2     2.33
3     1.5
4     2
```

My algorithm is:

create a dictionary for each id ({str:list})-> loop through all the columns -> for each column calculate the rank and update to the list in dictionary

but i think it is too complicated for this simple problem.
Is there any easy way to get the avgrank table?

Here is the code to create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4],'2014-01-01':[float('NaN'),0.1,0.2,0.8],
'2015-01-01':[0.1,0.3,float('NaN'),0.4],'2016-01-01':[0.2,0.5,0.7,0.1]})
```

Comment: Why is the rank `4` for value `0.1` in `2015-01-01`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's unclear why you think the [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html#pandas.DataFrame.rank) should be `4` for the first row value in the second column but the following gives you what you want. Here we call `rank` on the cols of interest and pass `method='dense'` and `ascending=False` so it ranks correctly:

```
In [60]:
df.ix[:, :-1].rank(method='dense', ascending=False)

Out[60]:
   2014-01-01  2015-01-01  2016-01-01
0         NaN           3           3
1           3           2           2
2           2         NaN           1
3           1           1           4
```

We then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the single column from the orig df and [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the result of [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html#pandas.DataFrame.mean) with `axis=1` for row-wise mean:

```
In [67]:
pd.concat([df['ID'], df.ix[:, :-1].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).mean(axis=1)], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'AvgRank'})

Out[67]:
   ID   AvgRank
0   1  3.000000
1   2  2.333333
2   3  1.500000
3   4  2.000000
```